# Postgresql error : String was not recognized as a valid date time

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am getting this error when I try to retrieve a date field  from postgresql from C#. As in `select datefield from table`.

The system on which postgesql is running is on IST timezone.  I can not edit any settings on the database or the system on which it is deployed.  What can I do in my code to prevent this issue?

UPDATE: The client is on MST timzone. Forgot to mention that.

UPDTATE2 : Attaching code

```
DbDataAdapter myAdapter = dbFactory.NewDataAdapter(sSQL, myConnection);
if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
       myConnection.Open();   
ds = new DataSet();
myAdapter.Fill(ds, dataTableName);
```

Comment: Please show the C# code you're using, rather than just the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are using a valid dialect on your `DbDataAdapter`? What type does your factory return? Meaning, what does `myAdapter.GetType()` return?

PostgreSQL handles min/maxvalues a little different than most DBs, and might return dates as:

- `'-infinity'` corresponds to `DateTime.MinValue`
- `'infinity'` for `DateTime.MaxValue`

Unless your adapter handles that I guess you might end up with a similar error.

I'm guessing you should be using `NpgsqlDataAdapter` from the Npgsql-provider, but you don't mention it somewhere.

EDIT: Found that there is a known bug: http://pgfoundry.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=1005522, but haven't found which versions this affect. It has to do with half hour timezones (e.g +3:30). I guess that is fixed in 2.0.8 as well.

http://pgfoundry.org/frs/shownotes.php?release_id=1686 some timestampTZ fixes was also present in 2.0.10

Comment: Devarts postgresql driver had a bug regarding `DateTime.MaxValue`  (dates were stored as 10000-01-01 instead of 9999-12-31) which could generate exceptions when reading from the table with other db drivers.

Comment: Yes, my adaptor is `NpgsqlDataAdaptor`.

Comment: Dates in my table looks fine.  In fact, I ported the same data to a postgresql server running on MST timezone and found that everything works fine.

Comment: Which version of Npgsql? in 2.0.8 they fixed some timezone bugs, mainly regarding negative timezones, but I'm guessing IST is a positive timezone? http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/npgsql-Npgsql2-Fix-time-zone-parsing-bug-reported-in-message-1005627-td2109151.html

Comment: My Npgsql version is 2.0.5. You think upgrading Npgsql might help?

Comment: We have an Npgsql which has been modified in-house, so migration to new version is going to be a pain.  I am now trying to debug through Npgsql source and try to track down the problem code. Will keep you guys posted.

Comment: You should probably be able to find the patches applied for the bugs reported, that would give you a hint on what changed.

Comment: I compared the code in Npgsql which parses dates from DB and converts it to Npgsql internal Date representation. That code has not changed across 2.0.5 to 2.0.8, anyone using Npgsql 2.0.8 can confirm that this issue is fixed/not fixed in that version?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading it as a string and then parsing it as a date in C#.

Like:

```
String date = GetFromDb();
DateTime realDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

See if that works, could just be a format error.

However if this dosn't help, Could you please post your code.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have posted my code, as you can see I am using generic code to query db. so your solution might not fit my problem.

Comment: Umm in your query, you can try converting the datetime format to MST, I am not familiar with PostgreSQL but it should have some datetime functions for handling issues such as these. Thanks.